# The turtle won't move in this code at all

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle as pen
# pen.speed(-1)


def triangle(side_length):
    for i in range(3):
        pen.forward(side_length)
        pen.right(120)
    print('triangle')

def square(side_length):
    for i in range(4):
        pen.forward(side_length)
        pen.left(90)
    print('square')

def house(side_length1, pos1, pos2):
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(pos1, pos2)
    pen.down()
    pen.left(180)
    square(side_length1)
    triangle(side_length1)
    print('house')

def house_street(size):
    num = size/400
    num = str(num)
    num = (float(num))
    pen.up()
    pen.goto(-200, 0)
    pen.down()
    for i in range(int(num)):
        house(size, -200, 0)
    print('house_street')

house_street(50)

pen.done()
```

The code is supposed to make a line of houses. But for some reason, the turtle doesn't move. I think it might be the fact that the file is a bit too big. Or maybe there is too much code.

Comment: ``50/400`` is ``0.125``. ``int(0.125)`` is 0. Your ``for`` loop will thus do nothing.

Comment: "Or maybe there is too much code." -- you seem confused by your code. You might try simplifying it down to a [mcve] so you can see very clearly exactly where it's gone wrong. [Debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an essential skill for any programmer, so I'd say, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `house_street(50)`, therefore the `num` in the first line of the code will be.

```py
num=size/400 #num=0.125
```

And `int(num)` in the loop will be `0`. So your loop does nothing.